# Code to make Android app ask for update?

Tags: android, apk

I'm making an app for Android that will not be in the Play Store and I was wondering if I could make it ask to update the app when I have an update ready. Also, would I be able to push the update out just by uploading to Mediafire, or would I need my own server? Thanks!

Comment: To start off, yes. And in order for me to answer your seconds question, what does Mediafire have to do with your app at the moment?

Comment: Mediafire is where I would be uploading my app so that I can share it. I was hoping I could host the apk on Mediafire for people to download the update from.

Comment: So this is not through the PlayStore?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a web service for it, which you can update after releasing new version. You can use this web serive in your app to check whethet the new version is out or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: hate you @beserk.. you are answering everything i wanted to answer :(

Answer (score 0):

As beserk answered .. i think i'll explain more in detail,though i'm not sure that this is the procedure that should be used ,but this is how i would do it .. make your app talk to a server once in 15 days or something so that it can check for a value in the server .. in your app get that value and is there is an update of the app according to your server ,just redirect to an another activity in the app so that user may not able to use your app again or keep a shared preference in the app like update=true and just check the shared pref value during the splash screen ,now redirect it another activity saying you need to update the app in order to use it ... i'm sure that there will be lot of other ways ,but this is the way i would do it